# Is there code to isolate .fill(mean) separately?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'BMI': [38.6, 14.5,'NaN' , 18.9, 46.3, 29.5, 'NaN' , 40.2, 25.6, 'NaN' , 28.6],
                    'Age_bin': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ]})
print(df)

     BMI  Age_bin
0   38.6        1
1   14.5        2
2    NaN        2
3   18.9        1
4   46.3        1
5   29.5        1
6    NaN        2
7   40.2        2
8   25.6        1
9    NaN        1
10  28.6        1
```

Is there code so the `NaN` with `Age_bin 1` will be filled in with the mean of `Age_bin 1 BMI`, and `NaN` with `Age_bin 2` will be filled in with the mean of `Age_bin 2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BMI': [38.6, 14.5,'NaN' , 18.9, 46.3, 29.5, 'NaN' , 40.2, 25.6, 'NaN' , 28.6],
                    'Age_bin': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ]})

df['BMI'] = df['BMI'].astype(float)
df['BMI'] = df['BMI'].fillna(df.groupby('Age_bin')['BMI'].transform('mean'))

print(df)

      BMI  Age_bin
0   38.60        1
1   14.50        2
2   27.35        2
3   18.90        1
4   46.30        1
5   29.50        1
6   27.35        2
7   40.20        2
8   25.60        1
9   31.25        1
10  28.60        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are passing `NaN` as strings while creating df, which is incorrect, you should pass it as `None` and Pandas would interpret it as `NaN`.

```
In [677]: df = pd.DataFrame({'BMI': [38.6, 14.5,None , 18.9, 46.3, 29.5, None , 40.2, 25.6, None , 28.6], 
     ...:                     'Age_bin': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ]}) 
In [678]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[678]: 
     BMI  Age_bin
0   38.6        1
1   14.5        2
2    NaN        2
3   18.9        1
4   46.3        1
5   29.5        1
6    NaN        2
7   40.2        2
8   25.6        1
9    NaN        1
10  28.6        1
```

Next, you can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to replace `Nan` with `mean` like below:

```
In [673]: df.loc[df.BMI.isna() & df.Age_bin == 1, 'BMI'] = df[df.Age_bin == 1]['BMI'].mean() 

In [675]: df.loc[df.BMI.isna() & df.Age_bin == 2, 'BMI'] = df[df.Age_bin == 2]['BMI'].mean()

In [676]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[676]: 
      BMI  Age_bin
0   38.60        1
1   14.50        2
2     NaN        2
3   18.90        1
4   46.30        1
5   29.50        1
6     NaN        2
7   40.20        2
8   25.60        1
9   31.25        1
10  28.60        1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the mean

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'BMI': [38.6, 14.5, np.nan , 18.9, 46.3, 29.5, np.nan , 40.2, 25.6, np.nan , 28.6],
                   'Age_bin': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ]})
print(df.groupby("Age_bin").mean())
```

and now you join the mean with the original dataframe to get an extra column ("mean"):

```
>>> df.merge(df.groupby('Age_bin', as_index=False).mean().rename(columns={"BMI":"mean"}), on="Age_bin")
     BMI  Age_bin   mean
0   38.6        1  31.25
1   18.9        1  31.25
2   46.3        1  31.25
3   29.5        1  31.25
4   25.6        1  31.25
5    NaN        1  31.25
6   28.6        1  31.25
7   14.5        2  27.35
8    NaN        2  27.35
9    NaN        2  27.35
10  40.2        2  27.35
```

and you overwrite the NaN in BMI with the mean column:

```
df["BMI"] = df["BMI"].fillna(df.merge(df.groupby('Age_bin', as_index=False).mean().rename(columns={"BMI":"mean"}), on="Age_bin")["mean"])
```

This should get what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Someone gave me the following code which fills in the correct mean without altering the order:

Comment: Someone gave me the following code which fills in the correct means without altering the order:                                                              
df.loc[(df['BMI'].isna()) & (df['Age_bin'] == 1), 'BMI'] = np.mean(list1)
df.loc[(df['BMI'].isna()) & (df['Age_bin'] == 2), 'BMI'] = np.mean(list2)